# Trigger.io Display loading image when using forge.tabs.openWithOptions

Tags: trigger.io

is there is any way to display any view or loading image when use forge.tabs.openWithOptions with remote url ? because it's gave me white blank page until the url loaded ??

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

However, can't you just "rework" your remote page?  For example, maybe you could "slim" down the content to just a "loading" image... but in the background load your content?

Comment: Thanks for your replay , the remote page is very small the problem with the internet connection between the mobile device and the website loading image will take same time that remote page will take,i was thinking if there is any way to display local view until the remote page loaded and displayed or any thing that tell the user i'm loading please wait ! not just blank white screen :)
i think Trigger.io should add option that allow us to inject and code to this model window until it load the remote url

Comment: Well you could have a **local page** that just looks like a loading indicator and contains the logic to load data from your remote end or forwards to it. In this case you'd open your local page using `forge.tabs.openWithOptions` and `forge.tools.getURL` to resolve that local URL. Should provide your users with instant feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add the module to your app and in its configuration specify the image location  which you want to display

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

use launchimage module

Go through this link 
https://trigger.io/modules/launchimage/current/docs/index.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't see a way to use this with `forge.tabs.openWithOptions`